# Using Array for java multiple types

Tags: java, arrays

I didn't put the array yet, I don't remember how to put it correctly. Tried alot of times but still failed to do it.
There's should be a calculation but I can do that, I have problem with implementing the array only.

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {
    
       BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    
    String courseCode = "", courseName = "";
 int marks=0, creditHour=0;
    String name, regNum, str;
    int tcreditHour;
    double tpointValue, gpa, cgpa, point, tpoint;
    
    System.out.print("Name : ");
    name = stdin.readLine();
    
    System.out.print("Registration Number : ");
    regNum = stdin.readLine();
 
  for(int x=1; x<3; x++)
  { 
       System.out.println("-----------------------Please enter course " +x+ " details-----------------------");
       System.out.print("Enter Course Code : ");
       courseCode = stdin.readLine();
    
       System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");
       courseName = stdin.readLine();
    
       System.out.print("Enter Credit Hour(s) : ");
       str = stdin.readLine();
       creditHour = Integer.parseInt(str);
    
       System.out.print("Enter marks : ");
       str=stdin.readLine();
       marks = Integer.parseInt(str);
 
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: First you define the courseCode as an array of 3, then you set it's values. You already know how to access it as an array.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not **programming school**. We are **not** here to teach you stuff that you can pick up from any decent book or tutorial! Meaning: did you even try to figure how arrays work? Instead of just dropping your code on us; together with some thing ... that you probably want us to code?!

Comment: ... or just using google.

Comment: create a custom class `Course` with the fout properties. create, populate  and put them in a Collection (like an ArrayList) the `for` loop. After the `for` loop create another one to do the statistics.

Comment: @GhostCat I am really sorry, I swear I did. It's just that I'm not fluent in english, I can't understand most of the parts.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you! I'm getting it now!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thanks for your time!

Comment: The only problem was on the variables declaration. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code :

```
import java.io.*;

class PBT {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String courseCode[] = new String[3];
        String courseName[] = new String[3];
        int marks[] = new int[3];
        int creditHour[] = new int[3];
        String name, regNum, str;
        int tcreditHour;
        double tpointValue, gpa, cgpa, point, tpoint;

        System.out.print("Name : ");
        name = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Registration Number : ");
        regNum = stdin.readLine();

        for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------Please enter course " + x + " details-----------------------");
            System.out.print("Enter Course Code : ");
            courseCode[x] = stdin.readLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");
            courseName[x] = stdin.readLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Credit Hour(s) : ");
            str = stdin.readLine();
            creditHour[x] = Integer.parseInt(str);

            System.out.print("Enter marks : ");
            str = stdin.readLine();
            marks[x] = Integer.parseInt(str);

        }
        for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n***********************COURSE INFORMATION***********************");
            System.out.print("Course Code     " + courseCode[x]);
            System.out.print("Course Name     " + courseName[x]);
            System.out.print("Credit Hour       " + creditHour[x]);
            System.out.print("Marks      " + marks[x]);
            System.out.print("Point      ");
            System.out.print("Total Point");

            System.out.println("******************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Total Point value : ");
            System.out.println("Total Credit Hour : ");
            System.out.println("GPA : ");
            System.out.println("CGPA :");
        }

    }
}
```

**But you should try to learn size of array and its indexing check this:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm

Comment: You should really use Java style declarations like `String[] courseCode = new String[3];` as it states in the tutorial you linked. Java is not C ;)

Comment: omg the only reason I have problem was because of the declaration of the variables. how stupid of me. I am so sorry! Thanks

Comment: @HeatKaiC your welcome Please accept answer if useful